# How to create a shader to mask using a degree offset from a central point?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm a little bit lost, and this is somewhat related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849663/creating-blur-filter-with-a-shader-access-adjacent-pixels-from-fragment-shader) I've asked about fragment shaders, but goes beyond it.

I have an orthographic scene (although that may not be relevant), with the scene drawn here as black, and I have one billboarded sprite that I draw using a shader, which I show in red.  I have a point that I know and define myself, **A**, represented by the blue dot, at some x,y coordinate in the 2d coordinate space.  (Lower-left of screen is origin).  I need to mask the red billboard in a programmatic fashion where I specify 0% to 100%, with 0% being fully intact and 100% being fully masked.  I can either pass 0-100% (0 to 1.0) in to the shader, or I could precompute an angle, either solution would be fine.

[image: Here you can see the scene drawn with '0%' masking]
( Here you can see the scene drawn with '0%' masking )

So when I set "15%" I want the following to show up:

[image: 15%]
( Here you can see the scene drawn with '15%' masking )

And when I set "45%" I want the following to show up:

[image: 45%]
( Here you can see the scene drawn with '45%' masking )

And here's an example of "80%":

[image: 80%]

The general idea, I think, is to pass in a uniform 'A' vec2d, and within the fragment shader I determine if the fragment is within the area from 'A' to bottom of screen, to the a line that's the correct angle offset clockwise from there.  If within that area, discard the fragment. (Discarding makes more sense than setting alpha to 0.0 or 1.0 if keeping, right?)

But how can I actually achieve this??  I don't understand how to implement that algorithm in terms of a shader.  (I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0)

Comment: @genpfault would you like to explain why it is that you always retag any opengl-es related question from including opengl, when the questions fully apply to both APIs

Comment: I'm maintaining the "Desktop OpenGL 1.0-4.1" (`opengl` tag) vs. "OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0" (`opengl-es` tag) distinction.  Since you specifically mentioned your usage of ES 2.0 I didn't think the `opengl` tag was necessary.  Feel free to revert the edit, I won't modify it again.

Comment: @genpfault I appreciate your point of view because it drives me absolutely insane seeing tons of cocoa-touch etc questions tagged as objective-c when they have nothing to do with it. But from my point of view, I tag anything generally relating to `opengl` as `opengl` even if I'm using the ES implementation - it casts a wider net for answers and makes sense to categorize. Tagging as `*-es..` I'd only do if it was a question specific to that implementation. Which I think very few questions actually would be (design q's perhaps). Thanks for the garbage collection and good luck on striking balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to this would be to calculate the difference between `gl_FragCoord` (I hope that exists under ES 2.0!) and the point (must be sure the point is in screen coords) and using the [atan](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/atan.xml) function with two parameters, giving you an angle. If the angle is not some value that you like (greater than minimum and less than maximum), kill the fragment.

Of course, killing fragments is not precisely the most performant thing to do. A (somewhat more complicated) triangle solution may still be faster.

EDIT:
To better explain "not precisely the most performant thing", consider that killing fragments still causes the fragment shader to run (it only discards the result afterwards) *and* interferes with early depth/stencil fragment rejection.
Constructing a triangle fan like whoplisp suggested is more work, but will not process any fragments that are not visible, will not interfere with depth/stencil rejection, and may look better in some situations, too (MSAA for example).

Comment: Thanks Damon. Can you be more clear about what 2 parameters I'd be using with atan? Also, how would I set this up such that the degrees result I obtain back is referenced against (0,-1,0) I.e. the line "pointing down" from A? Also my trig/geom is pretty weak; can you explain why atan is the right choice here?

Comment: There are two versions of this function, one taking a single y-over-x value, and the other taking an y and x value (the equivalent to the C `atan2` function). That's the one I was referring to (though you could equally use the other one). The two parameters would be .y and .x of vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy - A.xy). Do note that it's (y,x), not (x,y).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. It looks like I'm going to have to figure out what quadrant my answer is in to get answers > 180 degrees, and I haven't wrapped my head around how to achieve this but I can clearly see it's possible to adjust my inputs/output to atan2 to result in answers referenced against 0,-1,0 as opposed to 1,0,0.. I'll accept when I get a chance to try it out

Comment: This did work, thank you. To reference against 0,-1 and deal with the stan discontinuity issue I just did piecewise check in my shader if(from -pi/2 to -pi), else if(from pi to 0), else if (from 0 to -pi/2) and then evaluated there to determine discard.  Works great. And of course the next step if ever needed is to tesselate unit circle as suggested

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just draw some black triangles ontop of the red rectangle?

Comment: Because its not actually black I'm talking about; the black represents a drawn scene

Comment: You could use stencil test to selectively draw the red rectangle.

Comment: Hmm That seems possible by tesselating the unit circle but if I'm doing that work I think there's better solution that doesn't bring the stencil buffer in to play. I am looking to avoid the unit Tess route though I think