# Blur effect via OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've tried to find any blur effect realization. But I found only CPU realizations. They don't suit me, because I work with large bitmaps ([fastblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk) realization crashes with OutOfMemory with memory optimization) and I need use radius value with float point for flexible adjustment.

I think if I will use OpenGL ES facilities I would avoid problems from above.

Does anybody know solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 can definitely do the blur you need.  It will take two passes.  One pass to render it, and the second pass to run a fragment shader with blur.

[Here is another answer talking about it in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902143/793607):